# Shared library seems installed but I get an error anyway

Tags: shared-library, csh, tcsh

**Objective:** Install/run an app through csh or tcsh, it's a 3d liquid simulation app called realflow.

**Background:** I downloaded the app, try to run it through csh or tcsh. I get

```
strings: 'lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6': No such file
```

But after figuring out which package it belongs to and trying to install that I get:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version (9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04).
```

**Any ideas?**
Thankful for any suggestion, cheers

Comment: It's looking for the 32-bit version of the library.

Comment: Ah good catch, does that mean the app is 32-bit? The developer was very vague about this for the linux-version, is there a way to determine?

Or is it possible it could be 64 but they ask for the 32-bit of the shared library? Can I install the 32-bit version of the library even though I'm in 64? Sorry for noob questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is looking for the 32-bit version of libstdc++6. You need to install **libstdc++6:i386**:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion so I did that now and it still errors, when I look more closely I see it's looking to lib/and then the file, and I realized they're shipping a folder of libraries but the app can't find them. Does that mean I need to put that path in the .profile-file?

Comment: @izcho if the developer provided local shared libraries, their intent may be for you to specify the location using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`